# How can redirect address to another one in XAMPP?

Tags: xampp

Is it possible to make the `localhost` to be resolved to another address rather than `127.0.0.1`, like for example: `www.example.com` in XAMPP?

And in which configuration file I can do that if it is possible?

Comment: Do you really mean it or you meant the other way round?

Comment: I think that he means to add domain that points to his local XAMPP server and works in www, am I right?

Comment: @Baba : I don't mean from the web page itself I mean from the configuration file of XAMPP.

Comment: Have removed the PHP tag ....

Comment: @AlvinWong I had edited it again ,, hope to be clear now.

Comment: @Aan you can *actually* make `localhost` to be resolved into another IP address, though not in XAMPP, but nobody would want to do that because `localhost` is known to be `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: @AlvinWong I intended to do that in XAMPP, is there away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Edit your hosts file, add a new line for the address like:

`127.0.0.1   www.example.com`

On linux the file is in `/etc` on Windows the file is in `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc`

If you want to have different sites for `localhost` and `www.example.com` you have to setup your webserver for [virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can actually add an entry to the (don't know what to call) `/etc/hosts` file. It is located at `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`. You need to run notepad with Administrator rights, then edit the file and add an entry like:

```
# Makes `localhost` go to stackoverflow.com
64.34.119.12    localhost
```

Then `localhost` will get resolved into that IP address on your local machine.

But I **don't** see how you would be able to set that in XAMPP as it is not a DNS server. (Even if it is, the OS would more likely prefer `localhost` to be `127.0.0.1`.)

Also, you cannot point it to a domain name as it isn't a CNAME record.

---

Note: as you've pointed out the keyword `resolve` I assume you are talking about DNS entries.

Comment: @JvdBerg How am I going to change `stackoverflow.com`'s virtual hosts...